# css styled list has a whole in it, but why?

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

I'm working on a website and just realized, that my list of projects has a whole in it, and I can't find the problem:
[image: there shouldn't be a whole in it]

http://www.einfall7.ch/beta/category/manufaktur/moebel/

html code:

```
<li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <a href="http://www.einfall7.ch/beta/manufaktur/massives-nussbaumbett/" class="title" title="massives nussbaumbett">
                    <img width="500" height="313" src="http://www.einfall7.ch/beta/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/dsc_0142-500x313.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail colorbox-1376  wp-post-image" alt="Zoller Nussbaum Doppelbett">                <span>massives nussbaumbett</span></a>
            </li>
```

css:

```
#content ul.ref{
margin: -15px;
padding: 0px;
}

#content ul.ref li{
    margin: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 15px;
}

ul.ref li a > span{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 14px;
    height: 38.196%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: calc(100% - 30px);
    padding: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(0,0,0,0.25) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#26000000', endColorstr='#a6000000',GradientType=0 );
          -moz-transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
          -o-transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
          -webkit-transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
          transition: all 450ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
}

    ul.ref li a:hover > span, ul.ref li a.hover_effect > span{
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }
```

Comment: its because the height of spanbett div is 230px http://i.imgur.com/elZaHvJ.png and all the other div's heights are 225px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As the image in that div is a png,** **and others are jpg**

```
img[src$=".png"] {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

this css property is being added to the image inside it. **The hole is being created due to margin-bottom: 5px.** Remove that and your problem will be solved.

**Before removing** `margin-bottom: 5px`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcYrB.png

**After removing** `margin-bottom: 5px` : https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAZd9.jpg

Comment: @dippas yes exactly :D I was editing my answer so wasn't able to see yours.

Comment: It happens to me sometimes :) no worries

Comment: Thank you very much – I feel terribly embarrassed right now… :D
@dippas

Comment: You can upvote his answer @michael :D And, happy to help mate :D

Answer (score 1):

your issue is here :

```css
img[src$=".png"] {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

just remove `margin-bottom`,

Because that's the only `png` you have in your list, and you might **NOT** want to remove the `margin-bottom` because you are using it somewhere else in your site, the solution is changing the `png` to `jpg` src.

Comment: Thanks to you, too! If I could, I'd choose both answers as correct. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This issue typically happens in all projects where the divisions are simply floated next to each other and suddenly a div or image falls out of expected dimensions.

Solution 1:

Make all your tile divs to be of same height. You can set `min-height` for repeating div.

Solution 2 : Using Javascript:

When ever window is resized or new image is loaded,  calculate the maximum height of all div In a row and set it as the min-height.

Solution 3:

Why not make the tile little more intelligent with bin packing plugins like masonry http://masonry.desandro.com/